# Getting this error: curl: (3) Host name ' --url' contains bad letter

Tags: linux, nessus

I am trying to run this line on a linux machine:

curl --request GET \ --url 'https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v2/pages/nessus/files/Nessus-10.4.2-ubuntu1404_amd64.deb' \ --output 'nessus.deb'

but I am getting this error:

curl: (3) Host name ' --url' contains bad letter
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output
Warning: " to save to a file.

I ended up using: wget https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v2/pages/nessus/files/Nessus-10.4.2-ubuntu1404_amd64.deb

but it seems I should not have done it this way because now the subsequent line I want to run isn't working: dpkg -i nessus.deb

Answer (score 0):

The output for the curl was 'nessus.deb'. So to install you had to use 'dpkg -i nessus.deb'.

However, because you used wget, it did not create the output name, but just saved '*INSERTFILENAMEHERE*'. So to install it, you would use:

```
'dpkg -i *INSERTFILENAMEHERE*'
```

For example, you would have put in

'wget [https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v2/pages/nessus/files/Nessus-10.4.2-ubuntu1404_amd64.deb'](https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v2/pages/nessus/files/Nessus-10.4.2-ubuntu1404_amd64.deb%27)

Then it would say something like

''Nessus.deb' saved'

So you would then put in.

```
'dpkg -i Nessus.deb'
```

And it would install the package. In short, the reason why the line was not working was because the file was there, but the name did not match.